# git не видит изменений в ветке

Tags: git

git не видит изменений в ветке, после `git push origin remote_branch` и сравнением с `master` не показывает изменений, хотя было сделано множество изменений в файле но сравнивая с мастером не выводит никаких различий.

Есть подозренее что эти изменения уже были закомичены на этой ветке и удалены, а теперь git не видит этого коммита и соответвенно его изменений.

Вот такая картина:

```
git checkout -b new_branch

git commit -m "some commits"

git push origin new_branch

git checkout -b my_new_branch_2    

git pull origin new_branch
```

На этом моменте я получаю все коммиты которые были в ветке `new_branch` и удаляю некоторые изменения в файлах `test.txt`

```
git push origin my_new_branch_2

git checkout master
git merge my_new_branch_2
```

Тут я смержился с мастером.

Теперь когда пытаемся сделать мерж с матером с ветки `new_branch` с которой я ранее сделал pull то говорит что нет изменений в файле `test.txt`

Comment: Что значит "удаляю некоторые изменения"? Вы вносите новые изменения в этот файл? В какой коммит они попадут?

Comment: Вопросы задавайте, если что.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Что такое "ветка"

Это просто указатель на какой-то коммит. Все коммиты организованы в граф, в котором у каждого коммита (кроме первого) есть предок. Так за один коммит можно вытащить целую цепочку — до самого первого. Все коммиты, которые вот так вытаскиваются, называют «коммитами в ветке X» или «принадлежащими ветке X».

Предположим, было так:

```
A - B - C      master
          \
           D   new_branch
```

#### Что делает `git checkout -b`

Эта команда создаёт новую ветку, указывающую на тот же коммит, на который указывает текущая ветка:

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch_2   

A - B - C      master
          \
           D   new_branch, my_new_branch_2
```

То есть после выполнения этой команды ветки `new_branch` и `my_new_branch_2` идентичны.

#### Что делает `git pull origin имяветки`

Команда `git pull` производит мерж ветки из удаленного репозитория в текущую ветку. Если замержить коммит, который уже принадлежит текущей ветке (т.е. доступен по цепочке предков), то слияние не произведёт изменений.

Если никто кроме вас не пушит в ветку `new_branch`, то она указывает на тот же коммит `D`, что и ветка `my_new_branch_2`, так что эта команда ничего не делает:

```
git pull origin new_branch
```

#### Мерж предка

Если после этого сделать ещё коммиты в `my_new_branch_2`, но не менять `new_branch`, то вторая фактически будет «частью» первой. Ветка `new_branch` указывает на коммит `D`, который является предком `E`, а следовательно принадлежит ветке `my_new_branch_2`:

```
A - B - C      master
          \
           D   new_branch
            \
             E my_new_branch_2
```

Когда вы мержите `my_new_branch_2` в `master`, в составе этой ветки приходят и коммиты ветки `new_branch`. Мерж скорее всего у вас происходит по модели "fast-forward" – когда указатель `master` просто перемещается вперёд на указатель `my_new_branch_2`:

```
A - B - C - D   new_branch
             \
              E my_new_branch_2, master
```

Поэтому попытка повторно замержить `new_branch` в `master` не приносит результата.